# hash tables' application in cache

Tags: caching, hash

I read the wiki-page about hash-table.
then I saw something like this:

> Hash tables can be used to implement caches, auxiliary data tables that are used to speed up the access to data that is primarily stored in slower media.

I wonder how does hash speed the cache?
Can anybody tell me about it ?

Answer (score 1):

Each access to the cache will require the hash code of the lookup key to be computed, and each *addition* to the cache will likewise need to know the hash code. A smart cache which combines the two operations ("lookup by key; if it doesn't exist then fetch the right value and cache it") could *potentially* avoid having to compute the hash twice.

Usually hashes are relatively cheap to compute - and *much* cheaper than accessing the underlying resource which is being cached... and it's not like *all* the keys in the cache have to be hashed on every lookup.

In some cases hashes themselves can be cached - in Java, for example, the `String` class caches the hashcode when it's first computed. Whether or not this is actually beneficial depends on your situation, of course.